# Using SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule results in Object Moved Here rather than displaying the page content

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, webforms

I am using SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule found at http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx to prevent redirection of some HTTP 401 status and display a custom page instead.

However, I am getting Object Moved Here as the output. How do I display my custom page instead?

Page as follows

```
<%@ Page Title="Unauthorized" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="UnauthorizedError.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebFormsTemplate.UnauthorizedError" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>Unauthorized</h2>
    You do not have permission to view this page.
</asp:Content>
```

Code behind

```
Imports System.Net
Imports Appahoo.Web.WebForms

Public Class UnauthorizedError
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule.SuppressAuthenticationRedirect(Me.Context, False)
        Me.Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't realize SuppressAuthenticationRedirect already sets the status as HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized. Thus I should remove Me.Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized to let the page render.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports Appahoo.Web.WebForms

Public Class UnauthorizedError
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule.SuppressAuthenticationRedirect(Me.Context, False)
    End Sub
End Class
```